# Problem adding post meta and see chages on product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm adding these meta to the post id and correctly i see them added in database, but for some reason i have to update manually the post to see the changes on product page. Should I add some code to see the changes without update manually the post?

```
   $post_id = 12345;
   add_post_meta($post_id, 'test', 'string test');
   $args = array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'product');
   wp_update_post($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display meta tag in your product page you can use following code

```
    <?php $post_id = 12345;
echo get_post_meta( $post_id, ‘string test’, true ); ?>
```